# Python: How to create instance attribute by metaclass?

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm using metaclass to create property for new classes like this:

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self, internal_name, type_, default_value):
        self._internal_name = internal_name
        self._type = type_
        self._default_value = default_value

    def generate_property(self):
        def getter(object_):
            return getattr(object_, self._internal_name)
        def setter(object_, value):
            if not isinstance(value, self._type):
                raise TypeError("Expect type {0}, got {1}.".format(self._type, type(value)))
            else:
                setattr(object_, self._internal_name, value)
        return property(getter, setter)

class AutoPropertyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attributes):
        for name, value in attributes.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, Property):
                attributes[name] = value.generate_property()
        return super(AutoPropertyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attributes)
```

In this way I can write code like this:

```
class SomeClassWithALotAttributes(object):
    __metaclass__ = AutoPropertyMeta
    attribute_a = Property("_attribute_a", int, 0)
    ...
    attribute_z = Property("_attribute_z", float, 1.0)
```

instead of:

```
class SomeClassWithALotAttributes(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attribute_a = 0
        ...
        self._attribute_z = 1.0

    def get_attribute_a(self):
        return self._attribute_a

    def set_attribute_a(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError("Expect type {0}, got {1}.".format(self._type, type(value))
        else:
            self._attribute_a = value

    attribute_a = property(get_attribute_a, set_attribute_a)
    ...
```

It works great, if you always set the value before get the value of an attribute, since the AutoPropertyMeta only generate the `getter` and `setter` method. The actual instance attribute is created when you set the value the first time. So I want to know if there is a way to create instance attribute for a class by metaclass.

Here is a workaround I'm using now, but I always wonder if there is a better way:

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self, internal_name, type_, default_value):
        self._internal_name = internal_name
        self._type = type_
        self._default_value = default_value

    def generate_property(self):
        def getter(object_):
            return getattr(object_, self._internal_name)
        def setter(object_, value):
            if not isinstance(value, self._type):
                raise TypeError("Expect type {0}, got {1}.".format(self._type, type(value)))
            else:
                setattr(object_, self._internal_name, value)
        return property(getter, setter)

    def generate_attribute(self, object_):
        setattr(object_, self._internal_name, self._default_value)

class AutoPropertyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attributes):
        property_list = []
        for name, value in attributes.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, Property):
                attributes[name] = value.generate_property()
                property_list.append(value)
        attributes["_property_list"] = property_list
        return super(AutoPropertyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attributes)

class AutoPropertyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = AutoPropertyMeta
    def __init__(self):
        for property_ in self._property_list:
            property_.generate_attribute(self)

class SomeClassWithALotAttributes(AutoPropertyClass):
    attribute_a = Property("_attribute_a", int, 0)
```

Comment: You can't create an instance attribute without creating an instance.  Why don't you just put code in the getter that checks if the attribute exists and returns the default value if not?

Comment: you can assign default value to the attribute ahead of time, no?

Comment: @BrenBarn I once tried to create the attribute in the getter if the attribute doesn't exists. But in this way I will have to check if attribute exists every time the getter is called. So I changed to the workaround I posted in the question latter.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good use-case for metaclass magic.  Why do you want all these attributes to be properties?  Is it really just so you can force the type checking?  Sounds like you're fighting against python a bit here ..

Comment: @kkpattern: Why is that a big deal?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Like the workaround solution I posted, I can assign default value to the attribute ahead of time with a help of a base class. But I don't know if I can do this with only a metaclass. So I posted this question.

Comment: @kkpattern no, i meant you don't even need to base class. you can do it in metaclass using `attributes`, no?

Comment: @BrenBarn: You mean check if the attribute exist every time? I think it'll add extra overhead. Well both workaround are workable, I just want to know if there is a better way I don't know.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr the attributes in metaclass are the class attribute not the instance attributes right?

Comment: @kkpattern: You're already adding overhead by creating all those properties.  I don't think the overhead of an attribute check is going to make a major difference.  There are certainly complicated ways to get around it (e.g., have the metaclass inject an `__init__` into the class to initialize all the storage attributes), but there isn't really any reason to bother with that.  (I agree with HuStmpHrrr, though, that there may not be any reason to do what you're doing here at all.)

Comment: @kkpattern well yes. why you need to care anyway?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Well the actual `Property` in my application is a little more complicate than the example I posted. So I want to use the `AutoPropertyMeta` to save the time of writing the same code for a lot of attributes. I'm interested in the "inject an `__init__` into the class" way, can you post it as an answer. I'd like to learn some new tricks about python anyway.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: You mean why care about the difference between class attribute and instance attribute? Well, in my application the attribute may be mutable type like a list. If the attribute is a class attribute, then all the instances of the class will access the same mutable list. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @kkpattern: If you pass a mutable object as the default value to your `Property`, it too will be shared across all class instances, unless you explicitly copy it.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes. In the actual application, the `default_value` is actually a `default_value_factory`. The `setattr(object_, self._internal_name, self._default_value)` in `generate_attribute` will be `setattr(object_, self._internal_name, self._default_value_factory())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I meant about injecting a new `__init__`.  Please be advised this is just for fun and you shouldn't do it.

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self, type_, default_value):
        self._type = type_
        self._default_value = default_value

    def generate_property(self, name):
        self._internal_name = '_' + name
        def getter(object_):
            return getattr(object_, self._internal_name)
        def setter(object_, value):
            if not isinstance(value, self._type):
                raise TypeError("Expect type {0}, got {1}.".format(self._type, type(value)))
            else:
                setattr(object_, self._internal_name, value)
        return property(getter, setter)

class AutoPropertyMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attributes):
        defaults = {}
        for name, value in attributes.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, Property):
                attributes[name] = value.generate_property(name)
                defaults[name] = value._default_value
        # create __init__ to inject into the class
        # our __init__ sets up our secret attributes
        if '__init__' in attributes:
            realInit = attributes['__init__']
            # we do a deepcopy in case default is mutable
            # but beware, this might not always work
            def injectedInit(self, *args, **kwargs):
                for name, value in defaults.iteritems():
                    setattr(self, '_' + name, copy.deepcopy(value))
                # call the "real" __init__ that we hid with our injected one
                realInit(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
             def injectedInit(self, *args, **kwargs):
                for name, value in defaults.iteritems():
                    setattr(self, '_' + name, copy.deepcopy(value))
        # inject it
        attributes['__init__'] = injectedInit
        return super(AutoPropertyMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, attributes)
```

Then:

```
class SomeClassWithALotAttributes(object):
    __metaclass__ = AutoPropertyMeta
    attribute_a = Property(int, 0)
    attribute_z = Property(list, [1, 2, 3])

    def __init__(self):
        print("This __init__ is still called")

>>> x = SomeClassWithALotAttributes()
This __init__ is still called
>>> y = SomeClassWithALotAttributes()
This __init__ is still called
>>> x.attribute_a
0
>>> y.attribute_a
0
>>> x.attribute_a = 88
>>> x.attribute_a
88
>>> y.attribute_a
0
>>> x.attribute_z.append(88)
>>> x.attribute_z
[1, 2, 3, 88]
>>> y.attribute_z
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x.attribute_z = 88
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
    x.attribute_z = 88
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 12, in setter
    raise TypeError("Expect type {0}, got {1}.".format(self._type, type(value)))
TypeError: Expect type <type 'list'>, got <type 'int'>.
```

The idea is to write your own `__init__` that does the initialization of the secret attributes.  You then inject it into the class namespace before creating the class, but store a reference to the original `__init__` (if any) so you can call it when needed.

Comment: Also I want to know why shouldn't one use the injecting `__init__` trick?(Do NOT consider the deep copy mutable problem, we can solve this problem by a default value factory instead of default value). What's the dangerous?

Comment: @kkpattern: Because it's needlessly confusing and doesn't really gain you anything over just doing the check inside the getter.  Also I wouldn't be surprised if there are edge cases where it might fail (e.g., if some subclass calls `super()` in `__init__` and/or the class with this metaclass is not at the top of the inheritance tree).

Comment: When comes to inheritance it's indeed dangerous to  inject the `__init__`. Now I think doing the check inside the getter or create the instance attributes with the help of a base class is an acceptable way. But still happy to learn the injecting trick. I think it's still OK to accept this answer?

Comment: @kkpattern: Sure.  I only gave this answer because you said in your comment that you were curious to learn some Python "tricks"! :-)  This kind of thing is good to know about to understand how things work.  It can make sense to use this sort of injection to modify a class when it's created, but you have to be careful.  But injecting `__init__` is especially dangerous because it's basic and often overridden.